# SwipeRefreshLayout not update recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I use SwipeRefreshLayout .
 .recyclerview is not updated
 . In the setOnRefreshListener method, I wrote this command:
The recyclerview commands are currently not updated with these commands.
(I mean, when I edit the information from the server, it will not be displayed)

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        setupRecyclerView();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

});


private void setupRecyclerView() {

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
    getPosts(1);


    listemer = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {


        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            getPosts(page);


            Log.e("PAGe ", "" + page);
        }

    };


    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(listemer);


 public void getPosts(int page) {


            apiService.getPosts(page, new ApiService.OnPostsReceived() {
                @Override
                public void onReceived(List<Post> posts) {


                    openHelper.addPosts(posts);
                    postsAdapter.addpost(posts);
                    postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progressDialog.hide();

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you checked whether you are getting updated information from server inside onReceive() ? If you are getting updated data, then please post code for addpost(posts); method. :-)

Comment: You should not set the whole recyclerView again on refresh!! Instead just call getPosts()

Comment: add post :         for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
            if (!ids.contains(posts.get(i).getId())) {
                ids.add(posts.get(i).getId());
                this.posts.add(posts.get(i));
            }

        }